# ISC DHCP Server doesn't handout dns servers to clients

Tags: isc-dhcpd, bind9

Yesterday I setup a isc dhcp server on a raspberry pi together with a dns bind server.

Now the problem is, that the dhcp server doesn't hand out the dns server to the clients but if I manually specify the local dns server in my windows computer configuration every thing works correctly. By the way, all my clients get a IPv4 address from the dhcp server.

my dhcp server config: `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` :

```
#
# Sample configuration file for ISC dhcpd for Debian
#
#

# The ddns-updates-style parameter controls whether or not the server will
# attempt to do a DNS update when a lease is confirmed. We default to the
# behavior of the version 2 packages ('none', since DHCP v2 didn't
# have support for DDNS.)
ddns-updates on;
ddns-update-style interim;
ddns-domainname "mydomain.home";
ddns-rev-domainname "0.1.10.in-addr.arpa";
ignore client-updates;
# If you have fixed-address entries you want to use dynamic dns
update-static-leases on;


# option definitions common to all supported networks...
option domain-name "mydomain.home";
option domain-name-servers 10.1.0.2;
option ntp-servers 0.pool.ntp.org, 1.pool.ntp.org, 2.pool.ntp.org, 3.pool.ntp.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

ping-check true;
ping-timeout 2;

# If this DHCP server is the official DHCP server for the local
# network, the authoritative directive should be uncommented.
authoritative;

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
log-facility local7;


key dhcpupdate {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret MYSUPERSECRET==;
}

zone naef.home {
        primary 127.0.0.1;
        key dhcpupdate;
}

zone 0.1.10.in-addr.arpa {
        primary 127.0.0.1;
        key dhcpupdate;
}


# This is a very basic subnet declaration.

subnet 10.1.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.1.0.50 10.1.0.254;
  option routers 10.1.0.1;
  option broadcast-address 10.1.0.255;
}


# Hosts which require special configuration options can be listed in
# host statements.   If no address is specified, the address will be
# allocated dynamically (if possible), but the host-specific information
# will still come from the host declaration.

#host passacaglia {
#  hardware ethernet 0:0:c0:5d:bd:95;
#  filename "vmunix.passacaglia";
#  server-name "toccata.fugue.com";
#}

# Fixed IP addresses can also be specified for hosts.   These addresses
# should not also be listed as being available for dynamic assignment.
# Hosts for which fixed IP addresses have been specified can boot using
# BOOTP or DHCP.   Hosts for which no fixed address is specified can only
# be booted with DHCP, unless there is an address range on the subnet
# to which a BOOTP client is connected which has the dynamic-bootp flag
# set.
#host fantasia {
#  hardware ethernet 08:00:07:26:c0:a5;
#  fixed-address fantasia.fugue.com;
#}

# You can declare a class of clients and then do address allocation
# based on that.   The example below shows a case where all clients
# in a certain class get addresses on the 10.17.224/24 subnet, and all
# other clients get addresses on the 10.0.29/24 subnet.

#class "foo" {
#  match if substring (option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 4) = "SUNW";
#}

#shared-network 224-29 {
#  subnet 10.17.224.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-224.example.org;
#  }
#  subnet 10.0.29.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
#    option routers rtr-29.example.org;
#  }
#  pool {
#    allow members of "foo";
#    range 10.17.224.10 10.17.224.250;
#  }
#  pool {
#    deny members of "foo";
#    range 10.0.29.10 10.0.29.230;
#  }
#}
```

Comment: All seems ok; I would add it to the subnet declaration just in case. Are you sure it is the only DHCP in your network?

Comment: you can run dhcpdump in and connect one client. Then you can post the captured traffic and paste to pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Got it. My provider had reenabled the dhcp service of my router. After disabling every thing works correctly!

Comment: Are you the original asker of this question?  This answer came from a different account.

Comment: yes. i didnt understand why but its my question and thats the solution for my problem.

Comment: Things will be easier if you merge the two seperate account.  See: https://unix.stackexchange.com//help/merging-accounts

Comment: I would advise using our free services responsibly. You seem to be able to articulate well your thoughts and should be able to gain reputation easily.

Comment: I think I created the question without an account. Can I migrate a "non-account" question to my account?